# Overriding a method in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm creating a user library and extending the Selenium2Library.

And in my class I have a method called "select_from_list_by_value" and the same method exists in Selenium2Library.

Due to this I get the following error:

```
Multiple keywords with name 'Select From List By Value' found.
Give the full name of the keyword you want to use.
Found: 'Selenium2Library.Select From List By Value' and 'MyLibrary.Select From List By Value'
```

How can I bypass the above error? I'm in a situation where I can't change the name of the keyword in the test scripts which leads to unnecessary rework.

Comment: To be clear: you need a solution that does _not_ involve changing the test case? Do you want to use your keyword instead of the selenium keyword for all test cases, or just one?

Comment: Yes I need my keyword instead of selenium keyword for all the test cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly possible using [Set Library Search Order](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Library%20Search%20Order)

Thanks for Kevin O. pointing to me a [right direction](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/nNG_ePBieiU).